# SVGs + Words in buttons

Tags: html, css, button, svg

There's something fundamental that I seem to be missing about buttons. In my dream world, I could have a line of buttons, with either SVG only, SVG + Text, or just Text and they'd all live in the same space.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <button><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-twitter-retweet" /></svg></button>
  <button><svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-twitter-fav" /></svg> Words</button>
  <button>Words</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
button {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

[image: Buttons in row]

I can't seem to get the heights to all be in unison in the line, and to have the SVG Icon centered.

If you tab over the buttons, you can see the text content extends outside of the button, but I can't seem to figure out why as both font-size and line height should be the same.

[image: Tabbing over buttons.]

> Here's a codepen of a working example to play around with: https://codepen.io/theaemarie/pen/RGAwZj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret that you're missing is **[`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)** on `button`, which vertically-aligns an image next to text.

I've created an updated pen showcasing this **[here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EwPvxr)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Oh. My. Wow. So confusing, because flex-box's `align-items: center` wasn't doing ish. which I imagined was essentially the same thing. Also, when I've tried `vertical-align: middle` in the past it is never that easy.

Comment: Awesome; glad to have helped. In order for `vertical-align` to work, the elements need to be set along a baseline (`inline`, `inline-block` or `inline-flex`). If it wasn't working for you in the past, you probably didn't have the right `display` property. There's also a great article on it [**here**](https://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/) if you're looking for some further information :)